# For loop returning null in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using googles api to get 3 fields,
name rating and place review. Since place review uses another api call I created it as a function to get the data inside my place_review.

```
response.results.forEach((entry)=>{
         var restaurantName = {
          "name" : entry.name,
          "rating" : entry.rating,
          "place_review" : placeReview(entry.place_id)
        }
        arr.push(restaurantName);
        console.log(restaurantName);// shows only name and rating
      });
```

The extra function

```
function placeReview(place_id){
   console.log(place_id) // i see all place id via forloop.
   googlePlaces.placeDetailsRequest({placeid: place_id},function(error,response){
    if (error) throw error;
     return response.result.reviews[0].text;
  });
}
```

When I run the code , i get  `name : somename`, `rating : 4.5` and `place_review : null`

I thought the forloop will call the function and the return of the function will append the string to `"place_review"` not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: please check if the `placeReview` function is working or not

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan it is, I tried it seperatly

Comment: It is because placeReview make an asycn call to the api. You need to use a promise or an asyc flow control framework to syc your processes.

Comment: @CristianColoradoCervantes do I have to add promises or I can just call it .then()?

Comment: please look at my example below on promises for further reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `placeDetailsRequest` api is asynchronous, meaning it is initiated but doesn't complete right away. Consequently, the line:

`return response.result.reviews[0].text;`

is meaningless because there is nothing to return to.

Your `console.log(restaurantName);` will be run before the request completes so you will only get an 'undefined'.

To fix this, you will need to do something a fair bit more complicated ( will assume, for now that Promises are something you are not familiar with but that is typically the way people go once they are comfortable with the way asynchronous programming works):

```
response.results.forEach((entry)=>{
    var restaurantName = {
        "name" : entry.name,
        "rating" : entry.rating,
        "place_review" : undefined    // will be filled in later
    }
    placeReview(entry.place_id, restaurantName);
});

function placeReview(place_id, obj){
   console.log(place_id) // i see all place id via forloop.
   googlePlaces.placeDetailsRequest({placeid: place_id},function(error,response){
     if (error) throw error;
     obj.place_review = response.result.reviews[0].text;
     console.log(obj);
  });
}
```

Of course, you will only see the console results as each request finishes.

This uses a technique called 'callbacks' to manage the information that is only available at a later time. There is lots of information about this online and on SO.

Here's a version that you can run to see the technique in action - very similar to above but hard-wired some data.

```js
var list = [
  { name: 'Aaron', rating: '14', place_id: 21 },
  { name: 'Brad', rating: '33', place_id: 33 }
];

list.forEach(function (entry) {
  var restaurantName = {
    "name" : entry.name,
    "rating" : entry.rating,
    "place_review" : undefined    // will be filled in later
  };
  placeReview(entry.place_id, restaurantName);
});

function placeDetailsRequest(idObj, cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var result = (idObj.placeid === 21) ? 'def' : 'abc';
    cb(null, { result: { reviews: [{ text: result}]}});
  }, 2000);
}

function placeReview(place_id, obj) {
  console.log(place_id);  // i see all place id via for loop.
  placeDetailsRequest( { placeid: place_id }, function(error,response){
    if (error) throw error;
    obj.place_review = response.result.reviews[0].text;
    console.log(obj);
  });
}
```

Further Edit to Show Promise Solution:

```js
var list = [
  { name: 'Aaron', rating: '14', place_id: 21 },
  { name: 'Brad', rating: '33', place_id: 33 }
];

var allPromises = list.map(function (entry) {
  var restaurantName = {
    "name" : entry.name,
    "rating" : entry.rating,
    "place_review" : undefined    // will be filled in later
  };
  return placeReview(entry.place_id, restaurantName);
});

Promise.all(allPromises)
  .then(results => console.log(results))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));

function placeReview(place_id, obj) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Here's where you would do your google api call to placeDetailsRequest
    // if error then reject the promise, otherwise resolve it with your results
    //googlePlaces.placeDetailsRequest({placeid: place_id},function(error,response){
    //  if (error) {
    //    reject(error);
    //  } else {
    //    obj.place_review = response.result.reviews[0].text;
    //    resolve(obj);
    //  }
    //});

    // simulating with delayed response
    setTimeout(() => {
      var result = (place_id === 21) ? 'def' : 'abc';
      obj.place_review = result;
      resolve(obj);
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

There are other ways to approach this, but in this solution I am resolving the promise with the completed object. The Promise.all() function `then` either shows the successful results or the `catch` will display an error.

Comment: So whats the fix?

Comment: Whoever is down-voting, either don't or provide a worthwhile comment.

Comment: Hey rasmeister, I am testing your answer now, and No i did not down vote your answer :)  I will upvote it now :)

Comment: No problem Masnad.  I don't really care - just trying to help, but people really should provide comments when they down-vote so everyone can see what the issue is (if it is legitimate).

Comment: Updated to include working code so you can get a better sense of the delay that occurs here. I have added fake asynchronous request in place of the google api call that fires after 2 seconds. You will see the correct results after you wait a bit.

Comment: can you let me know how this code can be rechanged using promises?

Comment: See latest edits... I would highly encourage you to read the SO documentation on promises [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises#t=201703132134306110491). It is very well written with plenty of examples.

Comment: Thanks alot!  For all the help

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

**Promises**

You could use [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) in order to implement promises in your place review function:

```
function placeReview (place_id) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  googlePlaces.placeDetailsRequest({placeid: place_id},function(error,response){
    if (error) deferred.reject(err);
    else deferred.resolve(response.result.reviews[0].text);
  });
  return deferred.promise // the promise is returned
}
```

then you can invoke that function in your processing logic like this:

```
response.results.forEach((entry)=>{
    placeReview(entity.place_id).then(function(text) {
      var restaurantName = {
         "name" : entry.name,
         "rating" : entry.rating,
         "place_review" : text
       }
       arr.push(restaurantName);
       console.log(restaurantName);// shows only name and rating
    });
  });
```

you will not push the restaurant details till your call to the API is complete.

**Async option**

You could use [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) to coordinate your calls:

This function will be executed once per each entry:

```
function placeReview(entry, callback){
   console.log(entry.place_id)
   googlePlaces.placeDetailsRequest({entry.placeid: place_id},function(error,response){
    if (error) throw error;
     //this call back retrives the restaurant entity that async stack in a list
     callback(null,{
        "name" : entry.name,
        "rating" : entry.rating,
        "place_review" : response.result.reviews[0].text
      });

  });
}
```

Then you ask async to iterate your result array and execute placeReview for each one. Async will gather results in an array:

```
async.map(response.results, placeReview, function(err, results) {
  // results will have the results of all 2
  console.log(results); //this is your array of restaurants
});
```